# Remove the last comma from c loop

Tags: c

i have the belowo loop in c that print the prime number

```
  for(int i = 2; i<=arraySize; i++)
    {
        //If arraySize is not 0 then it is prime
       if (numbers[i]!=0)
        printf("%d,",numbers[i]);
      
    }
```

the out put after enter 50 for example is
2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,
i want to to not print the last comma how i can do it

i tried this code but not working

```
printf("%d%s", numbers[i], (i !=arraySize-1) ? "," : "");
```

Comment: `numbers[i]` is not `arraySize`.

Comment: `i<=arraySize` is usually wrong; a variable named `arraySize` is usually used for the number of elements in an array, and then the defined array indices would be from 0 to `arraySize`−1, but `i<=arraySize` results in the loop using `arraySize` as an index. Fix that. If the problem still occurs, edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: Assuming `for(int i = 2; i<=arraySize; i++)` does _not_ go beyond the end of the array (Without seeing the array setup, I would have assumed: `for(int i = 2; i<arraySize; i++)`), then I'd change: `(i !=arraySize-1)` into `(i !=arraySize)`. Note that if you _do_ change the `for`, then your original ternary would probably be correct.

Comment: The problem with your condition is that it won't work if the last entry in the array is `0`, because you printed a comma after the previous prime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the other answers overcomplicates things. I don't see any reason to have a test for every iteration in the loop. Instead, I'd simply do the special case first:

```
printf("%d", numbers[2]);

for (int i = 3; i <= arraySize; i++) {
    if (numbers[i]!=0) 
        printf(",%d", numbers[i]);
}
```

This will however need some additional code to correctly handle the case where `arraySize` is lower than 3.

But I would choose another approach from the beginning, and that is writing a good function for printing an array. Could look like this:

```
void printArray(const int *array, int size) {
    putchar('['); // Of course this is optional

    if(size > 0) {
        printf("%d", array[0]);

        for(int i=1; i<size; i++)
            printf(",%d", array[i]);
    }

    putchar(']'); // And this too
}
```

and then something like this:

```
int convertArray(const int *numbers, int *array, int size) {
    int ret = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        if(number[i] != 0) {
            array[ret] = numbers[i];
            ret++;
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple: Use a pointer to the "prefix" string, printed AHEAD of the next value:

```
char *sep = "";
for(int i = 2; i <= arraySize; i++ ) {
    if( numbers[i] ) {
        printf( "%s%d", sep, numbers[i] );
        sep = ", "; // I added a SP, too
    }
}
```

Here's an alternative that uses a "limited scope" variable to index a static string. For clarity in this example, the array boundaries have been adjusted.

```
int main( void ) {
    int numbers[] = { 1, 1, 4, 8, 9, 0, 7 };
    int arraySize = sizeof numbers/sizeof numbers[0];

    for( int i = 0, out = 0; i < arraySize; i++ )
        if( numbers[i] )
            printf("%s%d", &","[!out++], numbers[i] );

    return 0;
}
```

The negated boolean post-incrementing value of `out` provides the address of the `'\0'` to the first instance, then the address of `","` in subsequent instances.

```
1,1,4,8,9,7
```

Comment: Thanks,it solve by using pointer to the prefix

Comment: @codingacademybalqa Funny business?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of printing a comma after each number, print it *before*. Then you can use a variable to tell if this is the first number being printed, and not print the comma.

```
first=true;

for(int i = 2; i<=arraySize; i++)
{
    //If numbers[i] is not 0 then it is prime
    if (numbers[i]!=0) {
        printf("%s%d", (first ? "" : ","), numbers[i]);
        first = false;
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I like both the other answers but just want to throw in this error prone variant on the same theme.

```c
_Bool first = true;

for (int i = 2; i <= arraySize; i++) {
    if (numbers[i] != 0) {
        printf(",%d" + first, numbers[i]);
        first = false;
    }
}
```

If `first` is `true` the actual formatting string will become `"%d"`. If it's `false` it'll become `",%d"`.

Comment: UV... Insightful, and goes to show why there are so many skinless cats wandering around `:-)`

Comment: @Fe2O3 :-D :-D I should probably add more warnings than _"error prone"_ to the answer.

Comment: Agree about _error prone_ as the computed format likely weakens a compiler's format/argument checking.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yes, very much so. When doing things like this, one usually can forget the help the compiler provides with `printf`. Perhaps `-fanalyzer` catches potential problems still. Haven't tried.

Answer (score 2):

The answers already here are fine, but I'd like to add a "simpler" solution. Simpler in that it doesn't require any further logic or extra variables. It does, however, require that you *know* that the first number is non-zero.

```
printf("%d", numbers[2]);
for (int i = 3; i < arraySize; i++)
{
    if (numbers[i] != 0)
        printf(",%d", numbers[i]);
}
```

Comment: The pragmatic approach.  I like that too. `putchar('2');` even :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Well, I love your "add a boolean to a pointer" approach. Reminds me of my programming youth : D

Comment: @TedLyngmo Have we established that numbers[2] = 2? Then go ahead : )  Saw your bio - I wrote a Z80 assembler in BASIC for the ABC machines lol. Fun times!

Comment: @mmixLinus _"numbers[2] = 2?"_ -  I think so. OP lists the output as _"2,3,5,..."_.  _"Z80 assembler"_ - Wow! You actually did? That's so cool. I wonder if it was that one I used. :-) I wrote a VT52+ emulator purely in Z80 assembler. That was the program I used the most - to call my friends university computer to play Nethack (in 300 baud) :-)